# Make PWA start after OS reboot

Tags: android, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I want my PWA's service worker to run after the user reboot its phone.

The [only answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694633/progressive-web-app-start-at-android-device-boot/49695965) on the topic is 1.5 year old, and from what I read the field evolved a lot in that time-frame, so I was wondering if today it was possible yet ?

**EDIT:**

I double-checked and realized it's already doing that. After testing my service worker on my phone the first time, I rebooted the phone, and then notifications weren't coming in anymore. I therefore assumed service workers weren't surviving reboot. But it probably was my phone taking forever to load it, because I tried again and this time it worked ...

Comment: iOS has no support for service worker in the background.

Comment: True, I had read that they introduced PWA with iOS 11.3, but didn't realize it was that limited.

Answer (score 2):

iOS support has been added from version [11.3](https://love2dev.com/blog/apple-ships-service-workers/) (even if still quite behind compared to other competitors).

You can verify it on [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20worker) web site:

[image]

A service worker is a kind of web worker running on a separate thread, different from the one used by the web site.

You can have a [look at this article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) (part of PWAs series), if you want to get more details about Service Workers.

**Added from the comment**

The service worker gets activated automatically after the reboot. It is an independent process running on its own thread. That's also the reason why we can still receive notifications even when we are not currently visiting the target website

Comment: Thanks, but my question was to know how I can make my service worker restart with the OS's reboot.

Comment: What do you mean with restart? Would you like to reset the cache or having an initial state set?

Comment: Actually I double-checked and realized it's already doing what I want. After testing my service worker on my phone, I rebooted the phone, and then notifications weren't coming in anymore. I therefore assumed service workers weren't surviving reboot. But it probably was my phone taking forever to load it, because I tried again and this time it worked ...

Comment: Yes indeed. The service worker gets activated automatically after the reboot. It is an indipendent process running on its own thread. That's also the reason why we can still receive notifications even when we are not currently visiting the target website.

Comment: When someone gives a negative vote to an answer, should at least tell the reason. At least people can learn potential better approaches. Simply giving negative vote is just a sad behaviour.